# Center image vertical in div with overflow hidden

Tags: css, image, html, center

I think this is a classic one. I found a lot of similar questions but no answer.

I want to vertical center any image of any not-known height into a div with `overflow:hidden`

This is what I have right now:

```
.outer {
    padding-top:49px;
    height:49px;
    width:280px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.outer .inner {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background-color:blue;
}
.outer .inner img {
    position:relative;
    top:-50%;
    width:280px;
    height:auto;
    border:0px; 
    display:block; 
}
```

So the `.inner` is pushed to the center of the `.outer` by `padding-top`, so I get a "window" of 2 x 49px = 98px height. Then the `img` I thought would be pushed out 50% from the `.inner` height but for some reason i get a different number…

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or a JS Fiddle so we can visually see whats wrong?

Comment: I made a JS Fiddle (streched the height of the outer and pushed tohe image to the right) but it doesn't  even push the image -50%. I will add a screendump http://jsfiddle.net/joepdooper/3NSP8/

Comment: Is it absolutely imperative that the image stay in an img tag or can it be a background image in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation and solved it with a different approach.
For that I used the image as a background image of a div.
Code sample

```
<head>
    <style>
        div.imgbox1{
            width: 160px;
            height: 110px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-position: 50% 50%; /* for vertical and horizontal center alignment*/
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='imgbox1' style="background-image: url(http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/399232_10151118743727680_899168759_a.jpg)" >
    </div>
</body>
```

If using img tag isn't a must you can try this

Comment: Thank you Afzal, but I am hoping to keep the img for the love of the alt text and the complicated jquery which places the image into the html.

Answer (score 0):

First things first... An explanation of why you are getting the result you are getting.  This is quite simple.  Setting `position: relative;` (or absolute for that matter), and then setting `top: 50%;` aligns the very top of your image to 50%.  If you make the height of your image 1px, you can see that the 1px is centered.  Unfortunately there is no way with CSS to tell it to align to the center of the image rather than the top edge.

Now... A possible solution...

Assuming that nothing else is going inside this `.inner` div, have you considered allowing the image to determine the inner div's height via a margin?

Take for example this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NSP8/5/).

You can "center" the image inside the .inner div, by setting margin left and right to auto, and margin top and bottom to some px value...  In my example 60px.

If you want to obtain a total div height of 600px, and your image is always 400px tall, then a margin top and bottom of 100px makes a total height of 600px.  (400+100+100=600).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8311/8023199579_f52f648727_m.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    height:520px;
    width:520px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
    border: 2px solid purple;
}
.outer .inner {
    width: 340px;
    display:block;
    background-color:blue;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer .inner img {
    width:280px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 60px auto;
    border:0px; 
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

---

A second possible solution...

Assuming that the `<img>` tag does not HAVE to remain an `<img>` tag, then a very simple way to do this is to move the image itself to CSS, as a `background-image`.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NSP8/4/) for a demonstration of this solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="inner">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.inner {
    width: 540px;
    height: 340px;
    display:block;
    background-color:blue;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue url('http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8311/8023199579_f52f648727_m.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. Your solutions I understand. The thing is that I never know what the height of each image is and that the images will be cropped… Unlike my version in JSFiddle, but as I explained in my question on this page, my images will be cropped in the .outer div with overflow:hidden and with a height size.

Comment: If your images can not be moved to CSS as a background image then The only way I know of to get this done how you want it is to use Javascript and I unfortunately do not know Javascript.